# Como acessar uma função interna da biblioteca?

Tags: python

Estou aprendendo Python e me deparei com uma situação da qual não consigo sair. Estou utilizando a biblioteca py3270 e no init dela possui o seguinte:

```
class Status(object):
    """
        Represents a status line as returned by x3270 following a command
    """

    def __init__(self, status_line):
        if not status_line:
            status_line = (" " * 12).encode("ascii")
        parts = status_line.split(" ".encode("ascii"))
        self.as_string = status_line.rstrip().decode("ascii")
        self.keyboard = parts[0] or None
        self.screen_format = parts[1] or None
        self.field_protection = parts[2] or None
        self.connection_state = parts[3] or None
        self.emulator_mode = parts[4] or None
        self.model_number = parts[5] or None
        self.row_number = parts[6] or None
        self.col_number = parts[7] or None
        self.cursor_row = parts[8] or None
        self.cursor_col = parts[9] or None
        self.window_id = parts[10] or None
        self.exec_time = parts[11] or None

    def __str__(self):
        return "STATUS: {0}".format(self.as_string)
```

Sei que o STATUS me retorna todos esses dados, sei que posso obter os dados numa string e tratá-lo porém eu preciso conseguir acessar diretamente o resultado que de "self.connection_state".

Como eu poderia acessar diretamente esse resultado? Já tentei de diversas formas porém sem sucesso.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples assim:

Exemplo

```
>>> s = Status(b"Uma linha qualquer com varias palavras escritas para preencher todos os campos")

>>> s.connection_state
b'com'
```

Comment: Obrigado, tentei de diversas formas sem sucesso, consegui agora!

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, pode fazer um comentário do porquê?